# RedisTemplate issue while upgrading Springboot to 3.0.2 and java to jdk 17

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I tried upgrading java version from 8 to 17 and springboot version from 2.7.0 to 3.0.2.
Spring is not able to create the redisTemplate bean here.

I am using gradle version 7.6.

Here is the Exception:

```
2023-02-23 17:02:14,779 WARN  [main] o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext:  - msg: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webAppConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'idcsInterceptor': Error creating bean with name 'idcsInterceptor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customSessionManager': Error creating bean with name 'customSessionManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisUtil': Error creating bean with name 'redisUtil': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisTemplate': Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate]: Factory method 'redisTemplate' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Could not initialize cluster slots cache.
2023-02-23 17:02:14,873 INFO  [main] o.e.j.s.Server:  - msg: Stopped Server@7d2a6eac{STOPPING}[11.0.13,sto=0]
2023-02-23 17:02:14,901 INFO  [main] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler:  - msg: Stopped o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@21719a0{application,/api/contentstore,[file:///private/var/folders/hh/qs9cbbjd0pl6kkmp35k1p8m80000gn/T/jetty-docbase.19010.1981064911139296515/],STOPPED}
2023-02-23 17:02:15,262 INFO  [main] o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger:  - msg: 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-02-23 17:02:17,083 ERROR [main] o.s.b.SpringApplication:  - msg: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webAppConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'idcsInterceptor': Error creating bean with name 'idcsInterceptor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customSessionManager': Error creating bean with name 'customSessionManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisUtil': Error creating bean with name 'redisUtil': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisTemplate': Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate]: Factory method 'redisTemplate' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Could not initialize cluster slots cache.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
    at oracle.apps.bi.contentstore.Application.main(Application.java:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'idcsInterceptor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customSessionManager': Error creating bean with name 'customSessionManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisUtil': Error creating bean with name 'redisUtil': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisTemplate': Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate]: Factory method 'redisTemplate' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Could not initialize cluster slots cache.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customSessionManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisUtil': Error creating bean with name 'redisUtil': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisTemplate': Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate]: Factory method 'redisTemplate' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Could not initialize cluster slots cache.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisUtil': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisTemplate': Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate]: Factory method 'redisTemplate' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Could not initialize cluster slots cache.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate]: Factory method 'redisTemplate' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Could not initialize cluster slots cache.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:491)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate]: Factory method 'redisTemplate' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Could not initialize cluster slots cache.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 83 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [oracle/apps/bi/contentstore/common/redis/JedisManagerBoot.class]: Could not initialize cluster slots cache.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334)
    at oracle.apps.bi.contentstore.common.redis.JedisManagerBoot$$SpringCGLIB$$0.connectionFactory(<generated>)
    at oracle.apps.bi.contentstore.common.redis.JedisManagerBoot.redisTemplate(JedisManagerBoot.java:41)
    at oracle.apps.bi.contentstore.common.redis.JedisManagerBoot$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$redisTemplate$0(<generated>)
    at oracle.apps.bi.contentstore.common.redis.JedisManagerBoot$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at oracle.apps.bi.contentstore.common.redis.JedisManagerBoot$$SpringCGLIB$$0.redisTemplate(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
    ... 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisClusterOperationException: Could not initialize cluster slots cache.
    at redis.clients.jedis.providers.ClusterConnectionProvider.initializeSlotsCache(ClusterConnectionProvider.java:49)
    at redis.clients.jedis.providers.ClusterConnectionProvider.<init>(ClusterConnectionProvider.java:33)
    at redis.clients.jedis.UnifiedJedis.<init>(UnifiedJedis.java:122)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.<init>(JedisCluster.java:173)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.<init>(JedisCluster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createCluster(JedisConnectionFactory.java:413)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createCluster(JedisConnectionFactory.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet(JedisConnectionFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747)
    ... 104 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54022', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the JedisManagerBoot class:

```
package oracle.apps.bi.contentstore.common.redis;

import oracle.apps.bi.contentstore.common.model.RedisValue;
import oracle.apps.bi.contentstore.common.util.Constants;
import oracle.apps.bi.contentstore.config.PodConfigUtil;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisClusterConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class JedisManagerBoot {

    @Autowired
    PodConfigUtil podConfigUtil;

    public final String redisHost = Constants.REDIS_HOST_PORT;

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        String redisHostNamePort = getConfiguredRedisHost();
        List<String> clusterNodes = Arrays.asList(redisHostNamePort.split(",[ ]*"));
        RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfig = new RedisClusterConfiguration(clusterNodes);
        // get the redis password from SecretSvc
        if(!podConfigUtil.isTestMode()) {
            String password = podConfigUtil.getRedisPwd();
            clusterConfig.setPassword(password);
        }
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(clusterConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, RedisValue> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, RedisValue> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }


    private String getConfiguredRedisHost() {
        return redisHost;
    }
```

These are spring related dependencies from build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url = repoUrl }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '3.0.2')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencies {

implementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jetty')
implementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web')
implementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
implementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator')
implementation(group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter')

implementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-redis') {
        exclude group: 'io.lettuce', module: 'lettuce-core'
    }
    implementation(group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis')
}
```

[Here is the screenshot of my external libraries specifically spring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcMbF.png)

After looking at some of the suggestions on internet I tried adding commons-pool2 dependency but it didn't help.

Any suggestions or solutions would be of great help.